# Consulta Codigo Fuente lenguaje C

Tags: c++, c

Tengo una consulta , eh usado muy poco lenguaje C y me encontre con el lenguaje fuente, pero aparece que es la siguiente.

> ### Building Notes
>
> - We used Qt 5 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 to compile the project

y mi duda son las siguientes. estoy obligado a usar ese software y como realizo una compilación de un proyecto.

Gracias

Comment: Realmente, ahí sólo te están diciendo qué usaron para compilarlo y generar las librerías a partir del código fuente.

Comment: Exacto , tengo dudas es que supongo que se puede compilar con cualquier compilador de C y i es asi como se hace :S

Comment: [tag:c] no es igual que [tag:c++] ;)

Comment: Tendrás que tener instaladas las librerías de Qt. Respecto a lo de Visual Studio no sé qué requerimientos necesitará.

Comment: Instala las herramientas que ellos usaron. Luego abre el archivo de VS y deberia funcionar. En todo caso, tienen que tener algunas instrucciones de como compilar.

Comment: Si usaron Qt5 entonces no es lenguaje C sino lenguaje C++, ojo con eso porque no son lo mismo ni de lejos (hay muchas características de C++ que no compilan en C y hay ciertas características de C que no compilan en C++)